# Checking that all items in a list (numpy arrays) are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, equality

I have a function in my program that needs to check and make sure that all items in a list (which are all numpy arrays) are equal. The if statement that does this starts with

```
if np.array_equal(qstatnum[gatnum].count(qstatnum[gatnum][0]), len(qstatnum[gatnum])) == True:
```

This line gives the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am unsure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

Edit: 
Per request, full if-else statement in code

```
if np.array_equal(qstatnum[gatnum].count(qstatnum[gatnum][0]), len(qstatnum[gatnum])) == True:
    if np.array_equal(qstatnum[gatnum][0], [0,1]) == True:
        return qstat
    elif np.array_equal(qstatnum[gatnum][0], [1,0]) == True:
        return singates[typegat2](qstat)
    else:
        print("superposition not yet implemented")
else:
    return qstat
```

Apologies for not including, was trying to make the problem as small as possible.

Comment: Why the downvotes (how can I improve this question)?

Comment: @heather Are you trying to show that all arrays in the list are equal to each other? Or are you trying to show that all arrays in two lists are equal? What is the `len()` trying to achieve?

Comment: @Praveen, the `len()` was a rather bad idea, because I pulled it from another SO answer without knowing what was going on, but it advertised to show that all items in a list were equal. I am trying to show that all arrays in the list are equal.

Comment: @heather See my edit - maybe that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be using `array_equal` correctly. The inputs to `array_equal` must be arrays, whereas you seem to be passing `len` of something, which is a number...

If `l1` and `l2` are your two lists of arrays, you're probably looking for something like:

```
if all(np.array_equal(i, j) for i, j in zip(l1, l2)):
    # Do something
```

For example,

```
>>> l1 = [np.arange(3), np.arange(5)]
>>> l2 = [np.r_[0:3], np.r_[0:5]]
>>> if all(np.array_equal(i, j) for i, j in zip(l1, l2)):
...     print('yes')
...     
yes
```

**Edit**

If you're trying to show that all arrays in your list are equal to each other, then you can just show that all of them are equal to the first:

```
l = [np.arange(3), np.arange(3), np.arange(3)]
if all(np.array_equal(i, l[0]) for i in l[1:]):
    print('All equal!')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Praveen already mentioned, it looks like you want to compare two numbers only! If that is the case, then you don't need to use `numpy.array_equal()`.

Since, you didn't provide your code, I am unable to explain why you are getting this error. But I am sharing a simple here to let you know what the error means.

Example:

```
x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.5)
print(x) # [ 0.   0.5  1.   1.5]
y = 2*x
print(y) # [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]

if y <= 1.0:
    print ("ok")
```

This program gives the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

If you print the value of the boolean expression:

```
print(y<=1.0)
```

It prints-

```
[True True False False]
```

So, updating the `if` condition as follows make the program work.

```
if np.all(y <= 1.0):
    print ("ok")
```

So, I guess, you can do something like this to solve your problem as well.

```
if np.all(np.array_equal(qstatnum[gatnum].count(qstatnum[gatnum][0]), len(qstatnum[gatnum]))) == True:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it cleared up a few misconceptions I had. I accepted @Praveen's as it specifically answered my question, but your answer helped me as well. Thank you again; +1.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have numpy unfortunately, but here is how I would check if all items in a list were equal.

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != arr[j]:
        print ("items are not all equal");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this doesn't answer OP's question unfortunately!!